# What is the correspondence between combinatorial problems and the location of the zeroes of polynomials called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

In the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gian-Carlo_Rota) on the Italian-born American mathematician and philosopher Gian-Carlo Rota, it is stated that the one combinatorial idea he would like to be remembered for

> *"... is the correspondence between combinatorial problems and problems of the location of the zeroes of polynomials."*

Also, a refence [1] is given for this quote. Upon reading through the interview, though, I didn't discover any more about this correspondence, nor did I find a lot by searching for it on the web.

**Question 1**: What is this correspondence called?

I am also interested in how these two (which seem to me) disparate problems in mathematics relate to one another, so:

**Question 2**: How does this correspondence work? Any references?

Finally:

**3 more questions**: To what extent has this correspondence been developed any further since Rota's discovery? Are there any other connections between zeroes of polynomials and combinatorics? I know algebraic geometry is concerned with the study of zeroes of polynomials, so is there any connection between (algebraic) combinatorics and algebraic geometry?

Reference:

[1]  http://web.archive.org/web/20070811172343/http://www.rota.org/hotair/rotasharp.html

Comment: @rschwieb thank you for your edits.

Comment: Crossposted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127730/what-is-the-correspondence-between-combinatorial-problems-and-the-location-of-the

Comment: Answered on MO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexander Gruber mentions, this question has indeed been [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127730/what-is-the-correspondence-between-combinatorial-problems-and-the-location-of-the) on MO.